# Распознавание текста на отсканированном паспорте

Tags: php, изображения, текст, распознавание-образов, распознавание-символов

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо реализовать на PHP распознавание текста со скана паспорта. Для выполнения задачи были испробованы библиотеки Tesseract и GOCR (JOCR) — обе не очень хорошо справляются с задачей.

В текущей реализации при загрузке ровного скана с заданной пропорцией выполняются следующие действия:

1. Превращение изображения в монохромное.
2. Уменьшение яркости и повышение контрастности для устранения фоновых артефактов.
3. Разбивка нужных областей скана на отдельные изображения по сетке.
4. Распознавание текста с изображений.
5. Вывод распознанного текста в соответствующие поля для корректировки.

Распознаёт с точностью 50-60%. Практически в каждом поле требуется корретировка. Поэтому ищу способ реализации распознавания с применением матриц.

Пришёл к выводу, что нужно написать свой класс, который будет иметь следующие возможности:

1. Превращение изображения в монохромное.
2. Уменьшение яркости и повышение контрастности для устранения фоновых артефактов.
3. Поворот изображения на нужный градус для получения ровного прямоугольника по контуру паспорта.
4. Пропорциональная обрезка изображения по контуру паспорта.
5. Изменение размера обрезанного изображения до заданной величины.
6. Вырезка нужных областей изображения с текстом по сетке.
7. Разбивка букв из вырезанной области на отдельные изображения (текст на паспорте моноширинный).
8. Сравнение каждой буквы по матрице.
9. Составление текстовой строки.
10. Вывод каждой строки в текстовое поле для корректировки при необходимости.

Каким образом возможна реализация? Прошу подсказать, в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: Ни на что не претендую, но думаю, что смотреть стоит в сторону обхода капчи и ИИ.

Comment: @satanlucas, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Ваш ответ очень полезен, взял на заметку. Жду еще других предложений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делали подобное (но не паспорта распознавали). Использовали библиотеку ImageMagick.

1-2. Составляли список цветов фона документа, которые не могли совпадать с цветом распознаваемого текста. Эти цвета заменялись на противоположный цвет текста (текст #000  - фон заменяли на  #fff) для большей контрастности. [clutimage](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.clutimage.php)

3 . Использовали алгоритм для поиска прямых линий и поворота изображения для выравнивания. Вспоминаем геометрию и прямоугольный треугольник. Первый катет - требуемая горизонтальная линия, гипотенуза - имеющаяся линия. Точка отсчёта - точка соприкосновения этих линий. Поворот изображения. [rotateimage](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.rotateimage.php)

4 . Обрезка изображения. [cropimage](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.cropimage.php)

5 . Изменение размера изображения. [adaptiveresizeimage](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.adaptiveresizeimage.php)

6 . После нахождения искомых областей вырезаем. [cropimage](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.cropimage.php)

Также рекомендую прочитать статьи [раз](http://habrahabr.ru/post/241145/) и [два](http://habrahabr.ru/post/241263/). Статьи про распознавание капчи, но они Вам очень помогут в разработке своих алгоритмов распознавания.

Также если Вы собираетесь разрабатывать класс не для разового использования, то рекомендую почитать и про обучаемые нейронные сети.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам подходит использование платных библиотек, то обратите внимание на решение от ABBYY, разработанное специально для распознавания документов: [ABBYY PassportReader SDK](http://www.passportreader.ru?utm_source=ru.stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm).

Я работаю в компании ABBYY и с радостью отвечу на любые вопросы.

Comment: Только вашей рекламы нехватало. Ваше решение не Open Source, а в таком деле, как распознавание паспортов, этим пренебрегать нельзя.

Comment: @satanlucas вы и не просили OpenSource, или хотя бы бесплатное решение. Явно рекламный текст из ответа вырезали, а сама по себе ссылка на ABBYY PassportReader SDK полностью отвечает на ваш вопрос - ведь им можно решить проблему (пусть и не бесплатно)

Comment: @satanlucas прошу прощения за рекламу, постараюсь впредь быть скромнее. Могу я поинтересоваться, по каким причинам, кроме очевидных финансовых, вам важно, чтобы решение было Open Source?

Comment: @VitalikKudryavtsev, политика ИБ не позволяет использовать проприетарные решения.